# Drawing in GtkTextView, then clearing

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3, cairo

I simply draw specific content in a GtkTextView in a 'draw' signal,

on a next signal emission I draw different things in GtkTextView.

---

In the next signal invocation, if there is nothing to be drawn it clears all the previous drawings, which is good.

But when it is about to draw the new content, it draws all the previous at once, not only the needed one. Which is no good.

---

I tried many things to prevent this behavior, every possible combination with `cairo_save()` and `cairo_restore()` don't seem to do it.

How can I make it not draw every previous drawing at once, but the new one only ?

Comment: Why are you messing with a GtkTextView's draw signal? I'm not sure if that's supported in GTK. Anyway, how do you cause redraws? Are you calling something like https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw ?

Comment: It's the only way I can edit widget's own cairo_t. I connect the signal and inside the handler I condition-check. It behaves strangely and I can't understand it. Can't understand it's pattern at all. It will draw nothing the first time, the signal must be emitted several times in order to be content drawn. queue draw makes minor difference, but I use it anyway. The signal is emitted very often anyway, I think, mostly because of the cursor animation. (blinking/state w/e)

Comment: @UliSchlachter I want to make it draw different things, once, each time I want and clear the previous drawings. No matter what I try, it does already these things, but always something doesn't too.

Comment: If your idea is to just draw things, then consider widgets which are actually intended to be used as such, like `Gtk.DrawingArea`. If you want to have more flexibility and move things around more easily, look up `GooCanvas`. If you think about making some kind of word processor, you'll still want a canvas-like widget. You might get away with [`Gtk.Overlay`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkOverlay.html), if you want to draw on top of existing text - I don't have much experience there.

Comment: @jcoppens neither, because when using the "draw" signal you don't draw on top of the widget, but the widget itself. GTK+3 is now fully rendered with Cairo and the "draw" signal (which was previously an expose event) seems to be the only higher level way to change the way a widget is drawn.

Comment: Ok. The purpose is to change the TextView is  widget's appearance? Not to really make a drawing? Then probably TextView's draw signal is being captured to redraw the *text* content (internally). Did you see the function [`GtkTextViewLayer`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html#GtkTextViewLayer)? Is that what you need?

Comment: @jcoppens We could say I want to change TextView widget's appearance by making a drawing in it. I didn't know of layers, for first time I see them even mentioned. Maybe this explains the weird behavior I couldn't comprehend. I don't know how to use that still. AFAIC it is not referenced, it only says some C++ related mechanisms to do with `draw_layer` but yes this is what I want. The way I want it has been described as well I only don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The "draw" signal should be only used to change GtkTextView's constant appearance.

---

For what I want, this may work as requested:

```
void draw_on_textview (GtkWidget* textview)
{
    cairo_t* cr = gdk_cairo_create(gtk_widget_get_window(textview));

    // Do ALL the drawing AT ONCE here..

    cairo_destroy(cr);
}
```

When content needs to be removed:

```
gtk_widget_queue_draw(textview);
```

---

However this is still slightly different than the appropriate approach. As @jcoppens stated, `draw_layer` must be used instead. So I don't count this as an answer but some possible approach that I could alternatively use if there is no one else to provide the better way.